# How did Yom Teruah or Yom HaZikaron became known as Rosh HaShana?

Tags: commentaries, rosh-hashanah-new-year

I noticed that the Torah never call this day of Yom Teruah with the name Rosh HaShana. So how en when did it got the name Rosh HaShana? And more important how does one relate the terms 'Rosh HaShana' with those of Yom Teruah and Yom HaZikaron?

Comment: ותקעתם..  בכסה ליום חגנו

Comment: "Rosh Hashanna" is not mentioned anywhere in the Torah. I think it's first usage is in Tractate Rosh Hashanna in the 1st Mishnah where the 1st of Tishrei is listed as one of the 4 starts of a New Year. The Talmud debates when man was created if it was beginning of Nisan or beginning of Tishrei. Simplified "answer" for now. I'd have to complie several resources to make this a bit more thorough.

Comment: I read a very interesting article on this topic here:
http://thegemara.com/composing-rosh-hashanah-as-a-day-of-judgement/

Comment: I think you should separate this into two questions, namely: 1 - How it got the name "Rosh Hashannah"? and 2 - The relationship. These are different aspects and the sources to support each area are diverse and I think you'd get better attention if these were separated.

Answer (score 1):

Rosh hashona literally means "the head/beginning of the year"; it's simply an adjective and not a noun. (The day doesn't need to be given the name "Rosh Hashona" any more than the first born child needs to be given the name "oldest child".)

But if you want a source, see [Mishan, Rosh Hashonah](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/h/h28.htm), which beging "There are four Rosh Hashana's" and lists this day as one of them

Comment: to which rabbi do you source that the term "rosh hashona" is an adjective and not a noun? When you write, "There are four Rosh Hashana's" you yourself is using it as a noun.