How did Rosh Hashanah come to be known as "Yom Hazikaron"?
In Jewish liturgy (Yaale veYavo, Musaf, etc.) the main name of each festival is the one used in the Torah except Rosh Hashanah, which is called "Yom Hazikaron". This name is not found anywhere in the Torah, Mishnah, or Gemara, so where did it come from? I am aware of the thematic appropriateness of the name, and that "Zichron Terua" is mentioned in the Torah, but why specifically "Yom Hazikaron"?

I wonder if you used a different name if you'd be yotzei (Yom Rosh Hashanah or just Yom Terua)

In the middle Bracha of Mussaf, the judgement of R"H is described as Zikaron. So it seems that that was the terminology used at the time. It's the equivalent of calling it today Yom HaDin

Close to: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/76684/how-did-yom-teruah-or-yom-hazikaron-became-known-as-rosh-hashana

Not really close, although it's fascinating that we we went through several cycles of naming our festivals, and of the names in common use now, some are straight from the Torah (Shavuot), some from the Mishna (Rosh Hashana), some sort of assumed names of related rituals (Pesach)

Perhaps from the following pasuk we would have thought יום הזכרון would be more appropriate as a name for Pesach:

(שמות יב:יד) וְהָיָה הַיּוֹם הַזֶּה לָכֶם לְזִכָּרוֹן וְחַגֹּתֶם אֹתוֹ חַג לַה' לְדֹרֹתֵיכֶם חֻקַּת עוֹלָם תְּחׇגֻּהוּ

However it could very well be that יום הזכרון was chosen as a description for Rosh Hashana due to this which mentions a זכרון and is the ultimate pasuk we recite in the bracha of שופרות:

(במדבר י:י) וּבְיוֹם שִׂמְחַתְכֶם וּבְמוֹעֲדֵיכֶם וּבְרָאשֵׁי חׇדְשֵׁיכֶם וּתְקַעְתֶּם בַּחֲצֹצְרֹת עַל עֹלֹתֵיכֶם וְעַל זִבְחֵי שַׁלְמֵיכֶם וְהָיוּ לָכֶם לְזִכָּרוֹן לִפְנֵי אֱלֹהֵיכֶם אֲנִי ה' אֱלֹהֵיכֶם

Where the ספרי (במדבר עז:א) extracts:

אני ה' אלהיכם למה נאמר לפי שהוא אומר דבר אל בני ישראל לאמר בחדש השביעי אבל מלכות לא שמענו, ת"ל ה' אלהיו עמו ותרועת מלך בו, זה שופרות ומלכיות. ר"נ אומר א"צ, שהרי כבר נאמר ותקעתם בחצוצרות הרי שופרות והיו לכם לזכרון זה זכרונות אני ה' אלהיכם זה מלכויות. א"כ מה ראו חכמים לומר מלכיות תחלה ואח"כ זכרונות ושופרות. אלא המליכהו עליך תחלה ואחר כך בקש רחמים לפניו כדי שתזכר לך

This is encapsulated by Rashi on that pasuk with:

אני ה' אלהיכם. מִכָּאן לָמַדְנוּ מַלְכִיּוֹת עִם זִכְרוֹנוֹת וְשׁוֹפָרוֹת, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר "וּתְקַעְתֶּם" —זוֹ שׁוֹפָרוֹת, "לְזִכָּרוֹן" — זוֹ זִכְרוֹנוֹת, "אֲנִי ה' אֱלֹהֵיכֶם" — זוֹ מַלְכִיּוֹת וְכוּ' (ספרי)

The אבודרהם also seems to point to this pasuk when discussing the nature of Rosh Hashana as יום הזכרון:

אתה בחרתנו פירשנוהו בתפלת פסח. ואומ' ותתן לנו ה' אלקינו באהבה את יום הזכרון הזה. ואין צריך להזכיר ראש חדש ולומ' את יום ראש החדש הזה דאמרי' בפ' בכל מערבין דזכרון אחד עולה לכאן ולכאן פי' כשאומר את יום הזכרון הזה גם ראש חדש בכלל שבשניהם כתוב לשון זכירה שנאמ' וביום שמחתכם ובמועדיכם ובראשי חדשיכם וגו' והיו לכם לזכרון לפני אלקיכם.


This question is fully explored in the book "Rendzevous with God" by Rabbi Nathan Laufer, chapter 3. The problem, is that the act of Creation occured long before the time that the Jewish history start. Therefore, it cannot serve as a day of "rememberance" that occured in the Jewish history. He explains that it is not a simple day of rememberance that we observe, but specifically the rememberance of terua. (in what follows I will be quoting the book even if I will not use the quotation marks for readability). In the book of Bamidbar 10:1-10, the Torah tells us that a terua is one of two musical notes produced by the trumpet or the shofar.

The terua was blown in two sets of circumstances: as a signal to the Jewish people to move their encampment from one place to another (Bamidbar 10:5-6), and in the event of war, to "remind G-d" of their precarious plight, through the tremulous, staccato sound of their blowing (Bamidbar 10:9). An alternative shofar sound , the tekia, was blown to gather (uvehak'hil) the people (Bamidbar 10:7).

There is only one place in the Torah prior to Vayikra 23, the chapter of the holidays, where blowing of shofar on Rosh Hashanah is mentioned. The place is in the book of Shemos in the parshas Yisro during the revelation of G-d's presence at Mount Sinai. There the Torah speaks three times of the sounding of shofar:

Shemos 19:16: On the third day, as morning dawned, there was thunder (koloth), and lightning, and a dense cloud upon the mountain, and a very loud blast (kol) of the horn; and all the people who were in the camp trembled.
Shemos 19:19: The blare (kol) of the horn grew louder and louder. As Moses spoke, G-d answered him in sound (bekol).
Shemos 20:15: All the people witnessed the thunder (koloth) and lightning, the blare (kol) of the horn and the mountain smoking; and when the people saw it, they fell back and stood at a distance.

Therefore, the day of Rosh Hashanah is the day of rememberance of our experience of standing at mount Sinai as we were receiving the Torah.
There is additional biblical support for this thesis from the book of Nehemiah, ch. 8. It describes a dramatic ceremony led by Ezra the Scribe after the Jewish people returned from the Babylonian exile. The ceremony took place on the 1st day of the 7th month. During the ceremony people gathered as one and responded Amen in fear and trembling as Ezra standing on a raised platform (suggesting a mountain) revealed  to the confused and struggling returnees to the Land of Israel the Torah of Moshe that they had forgotten. Apparently, Ezra also saw a linkage between the day of Rosh Hashanah and the awe-inspiring revelation of the Torah to the Jewish people who stood at the foot of Mount Sinai.
This connection goes deep through many minhagim of Rosh Hashanah, such as sounding 3 different sounds of shofar: sound of shofar (kol), sound of thunder (koloth), sound of G-d's voice. We sound shofar after reading 10 verses hinting to 10 commandments. We sound 3 sets of Shofar blows after Malkiyoth, Zikhronoth, and Shofaroth corresponding to the quoted 3 verses. There is much more that is discussed in the book on this beautiful subject.

I always thought it was to remember that Adam sinned on that day and was forgiven. Likewise, we want to be forgiven.
